# Does the need to make the code simpler justify the use of wrong abstractions?

Tags: c#, collections, queue

Suppose we have a `CommandRunner` class that runs `Commands`, when a `Command` is created it's kept in the `processingQueue` for proccessing, if the execution of the `Command` finishes with errors the `Command` is moved to the `faultedQueue` for later processing but when everything is OK the `Command` is moved to the `archiveQueue`, the `archiveQueue` is not going to be processed in any way

the CommandRunner is something like this

```
class CommandRunner
{
  public CommandRunner(IQueue<Command> processingQueue, 
                       IQueue<Command> faultedQueue, 
                       IQueue<Command> archiveQueue)
  {
     this.processingQueue = processingQueue;
     this.faultedQueue= faultedQueue;
     this.archiveQueue= archiveQueue;
  }

  public void RunCommands()
  {
     while(processingQueue.HasItems)
     {
        var current = processingQueue.Dequeue();
        var result = current.Run();
        if(result.HasError)
           curent.MoveTo(faultedQueue);
        else 
           curent.MoveTo(archiveQueue);
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

The `CommandeRunner` recives the three dependecies as a `PersistentQueue` the `PersistentQueue` is responsible for the long term storage of the `Commands` and so we free the `CommandRunner` from handling this

And the only purpose of  the `archiveQueue` is to keep the design homogenous, to keep the `CommandRunner` persistence ignorant and with few dependencies

for example we can imagine a Property like this

```
IEnumerable<Command> AllCommands
{
    get
    {
        return Enumerate(archiveQueue).Union(processingQueue).Union(faultedQueue);
    }
}
```

many portions of the class need to do so(handle the Archive as a Queue to make the code simpler as shown above)

Does it make sense to use a Queue even if it's not the best abstraction, or do I have to use another abstraction for the archive concept.
what are other alternatives to meet these requirement?

Comment: The name of the datastructure doesn't have to match the abstraction.  Just change your variable name to `archivedCommands` or something that doesn't claim it's something it isn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's not about the name it's about the data structure IQueue that is being injected into the CommandRunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that code, especially running code usually gets tangled and messy as time pass. To combat this, good names, good design, and meaningful comments come into play.

If you don't going to process the `archiveQueue`, and it's just a storage for messages that has been successfully processed, you can always store it as a different type (list, collection, set, whatever suits your needs), and then choose one of the following two:

1. Keep the name `archiveQueue` and change the underlying type. I would leave a comment where it's defined (or injected) saying : *Notice that this might not be an actual queue. Name is for consistency reasons only.*
2. Change the name to `archiveRepository` or something similar, while keeping the queue type. Obviously, since it's still a queue, you'll leave a comment saying: *Notice, this is actually a queue*.

Another thing to keep in mind, is that if you have `n` people working on your code base, you'll probably get `n+1` different perferences about which way it shoud be done :)

Comment: Both names and Types are both about __contracts/promises__ and about __expectation/invitations__. Since Queue has nothing over a List the first point is moot; but it does raise __expectations__ as to how it is/will be/should be used which are __wrong__. Especially if you won't ever remove the first Items the name Queue is misleading. So I would change the name to ArchiveList or simply Archive. This still sounds like keeping a chronological order but avoids inviting to dequeue..

Answer (score 0):

Queue is a useful structure when you need to take care about the order of items inside it. If you need in your command post process, take care about the orders commands ran, then the queue can be a good choice.

If you don't need info about the order or commands, maybe you can use a List (on System.Collections namespace).

I think your choice are good, in the same case, I'll use a queues, we have a good example with OS design principles, inside OS (on Kernel) the process are queued for execution, clearly the OS queues are more complicated because they have other variables in mind like priority, and CPU utilization, but we can learn about the use of queues like data structures in process management.